# Pandas Sorting and Regrouping Using Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas

This is the sample data -

```
Product     Type        Name    Time        Value
Product a   Medicare    CVS     2018-10-05  10
Product a   Medicare    Cigna   2018-10-05  20
Product a   Medicare    United  2018-10-05  30
Product a   Medicare    Humana  2018-10-05  40
Product a   Medicare    Centene 2018-10-05  50
Product a   Comm        CVS     2018-10-05  20
Product a   Comm        Cigna   2018-10-05  30
Product a   Comm        United  2018-10-05  40
Product a   Comm        Humana  2018-10-05  50
Product a   Comm        Centene 2018-10-05  60
Product a   Medicare    CVS     2019-10-03  30
Product a   Medicare    Cigna   2019-10-03  20
Product a   Medicare    United  2019-10-03  10
Product a   Medicare    Humana  2019-10-03  5
Product a   Medicare    Centene 2019-10-03  12
Product a   Comm        CVS     2019-10-03  87
Product a   Comm        Cigna   2019-10-03  43
Product a   Comm        United  2019-10-03  50
Product a   Comm        Humana  2019-10-03  30
Product a   Comm        Centene 2019-10-03  90
```

First I need to find the latest week in 'Time'.

In the table above it is 2019-10-03.

Now for that week, I need to sort/find the top 2 'Name' by value for each 'Type'.

Then, I need to create a dataframe like this below -

The top 2 'Name' for 'Medicare' for the week 2019-10-03 is CVS, and Cigna.
The top 2 'Name' for 'Comm' for the week 2019-10-03 is Centene, and CVS.

```
Product    Type         Name    Time       Value
Product a   Medicare    CVS     2018-10-05  10
Product a   Medicare    Cigna   2018-10-05  20
Product a   Comm        Centene 2018-10-05  60
Product a   Comm        CVS     2018-10-05  20
Product a   Medicare    CVS     2019-10-03  30
Product a   Medicare    Cigna   2019-10-03  20
Product a   Comm        Centene 2019-10-03  90
Product a   Comm        CVS     2019-10-03  87
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have Values 10 and 20 for the first two records and not Values 40 and 50.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter `Product`, `Type` and `Name` combination for latest datetime and then use `merge` for filter combinations for all datetimes:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df1= (df[df['Time'].eq(df['Time'].max())]
      .sort_values('Value', ascending=False)\
      .groupby(['Product', 'Type'])\
      .head(2))
print (df1)
      Product      Type     Name       Time  Value
19  Product a      Comm  Centene 2019-10-03     90
15  Product a      Comm      CVS 2019-10-03     87
10  Product a  Medicare      CVS 2019-10-03     30
11  Product a  Medicare    Cigna 2019-10-03     20

df = (df.merge(df1[['Product','Type', 'Name']])
        .sort_values(['Product','Time','Type','Value'], 
                     ascending=[True, True,True, False]))
print (df)
     Product      Type     Name       Time  Value
6  Product a      Comm  Centene 2018-10-05     60
4  Product a      Comm      CVS 2018-10-05     20
2  Product a  Medicare    Cigna 2018-10-05     20
0  Product a  Medicare      CVS 2018-10-05     10
7  Product a      Comm  Centene 2019-10-03     90
5  Product a      Comm      CVS 2019-10-03     87
1  Product a  Medicare      CVS 2019-10-03     30
3  Product a  Medicare    Cigna 2019-10-03     20
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, sort the dataframe first, then group by and use head:

```
df.sort_values('Value', ascending=False)\
  .groupby(['Product', 'Type', 'Time'])\
  .head(2)\
  .sort_index()
```

Output:

```
      Product      Type     Name        Time  Value
3   Product a  Medicare   Humana  2018-10-05     40
4   Product a  Medicare  Centene  2018-10-05     50
8   Product a      Comm   Humana  2018-10-05     50
9   Product a      Comm  Centene  2018-10-05     60
10  Product a  Medicare      CVS  2019-10-03     30
11  Product a  Medicare    Cigna  2019-10-03     20
15  Product a      Comm      CVS  2019-10-03     87
19  Product a      Comm  Centene  2019-10-03     90
```